# Processing is giving a "bad identifier" error. I'm not quite sure what that means

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, processing, visualization

I am trying to make a simple data visualization chart. This code is supposed to result in a small dot graph.

However, processing is giving me a 'bad identifier' syntax error. It's saying that maybe I forgot a variable or something.

It doesn't make sense to me, because I am following a tutorial and coded the exact same thing so. I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

```
color[] dessert = (#9F9694, #791F33, #BA3D49, #F1E6D4, #E2E1DC);
color[] pallette = dessert;

size(600,200);
background(palette[0]);
smooth();

int[] fibonacci = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377};
for(int i < 0; i < fibonacci.length; i++) { 
  stroke(palette[1]);
  strokeWeight(2);
  float x = fibonacci[i];
  ellipse(x, height/2, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's Java? Can you give a bit more complete code, like at least a method where this code resides in? Where do `size()`, `background()`, `smooth()`, `stroke()`, `strokeWeight()`, `ellipse()` come from? what type is `color` exactly? where does `height` come from? Just soooo many possibilities for syntax errors...

Comment: You probably meant `for(int i = 0; i < fibonacci.length; i++) {`. (I.e. `=` instead of `<`.)

Comment: @Jens @cyberbrain this is about [Processing](https://processing.org/), `color` is a valid type, `#xxxxxx` is the right way to specify colors and `size`, `background` etc. are defined.

Comment: @Jules are you sure arrays are defined with normal parens instead of braces, like you're doing in the first line? Where are you getting that error? What tutorial are you following?

Comment: Also, you mispelled "palette" in the declaration.

Comment: Once you fixed those issues (including the one pointed out by aioobe in another comment) you should be able to run the example and see what you probably expect to see (circles further and further apart).

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Processing works with `setup()` and `draw()` methods, which are both missing from your snippet.
2. To make a copy of an array, you will have to use the `arrayCopy()` method
3. The `for` loop declaration is incorrect. Instead of `for(int i < 0; ...` you should place `for(int i = 0; ...`

I also removed the `pallete` array, as it does not serve any purpose in the current snippet.

With these changes, the snippet was able to launch and successfully run:

```
color[] dessert = {#9F9694, #791F33, #BA3D49, #F1E6D4, #E2E1DC};

void setup(){
  size(600,200);
  background(dessert[0]);
  smooth();
}

void draw(){
  int[] fibonacci = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377};
  for(int i = 0; i < fibonacci.length; i++) { 
    stroke(dessert[1]);
    strokeWeight(2);
    float x = fibonacci[i];
    ellipse(x, height/2, 20, 20);
  }
}
```